# Swapi API pagination using (data.next) vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, rest

I have this async function to get three separate requests from the swapi API to retrieve data. However, I'm only getting back the first page of data as it's paginated. I know I have to create a loop for data.next to make new requests but I'm unsure the best way to run it through my function.

```
(async function getData() {

//Utility Functions for fetch
    const urls = ["https://swapi.co/api/planets/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/", "https://swapi.co/api/people/"];
    const checkStatus = res => res.ok ? Promise.resolve(res) : Promise.reject(new Error(res.statusText));
    const parseJSON = response => response.json();

//Get Data
    await Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)
      .then(checkStatus)
      .then(parseJSON)
      .catch(error => console.log("There was a problem!", error))))
      .then(data => {
        let planets = data[0].results,
            films = data[1].results,
            people = data[2].results;
        buildData(films, planets, people);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access all the `data.results` keys in the loop, which misses the point of using `Promise.all`. `Promise.all` collects all the results from promises and stores it in a single array when all the promises are resolved.

So wait for the promises to resolve and use the array returned from `Promise.all` to build your data.

To get all the pages you need to have a recursive function. Which means that this function will keep calling itself until a condition is met. Sort of like a loop but with callbacks.

Every time you fetch a page check if the there is a next page by checking the `next` property in the response object. If there is call the `getAllPages` again until there are no more pages left. At the same time all the results are concatenated in a single array. That array is passed on to the next call which concatenates it again with the result. And at the end the `collection` variable, which contains all the concatenated arrays, is returned.

Let me know if you have any questions regarding the code.

```
(async function getData() {

  //Utility Functions for fetch
  const urls = ["https://swapi.co/api/planets/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/", "https://swapi.co/api/people/"];
  const checkStatus = res => res.ok ? Promise.resolve(res) : Promise.reject(new Error(res.statusText));
  const parseJSON = response => response.json();

  // Get a single endpoint.
  const getPage = url => fetch(url)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .catch(error => console.log("There was a problem!", error));

  // Keep getting the pages until the next key is null.
  const getAllPages = async (url, collection = []) => {
    const { results, next } = await getPage(url);
    collection = [...collection, ...results];
    if (next !== null) {
      return getAllPages(next, collection);
    }
    return collection;
  }

  // Select data out of all the pages gotten.
  const [ planets, films, people ] = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => getAllPages(url)));
  buildData(films, planets, people);

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the promise.all, how would i loop over the pagination in this case?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to get all pages of data for each data type (planets, films, people).

I know there's a key data.next to give a new page url but i'm unsure how to loop over that to access them all into one variable, each.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a recursive function that gets all the pages until there are no more pages to fetch.